# multiple views in ui-router state not working .. no errors reported

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

Hi I am working on multiple nested views in a single state like in this plunkr[http://plnkr.co/edit/FKdwViJllUKGoYIAWIED?p=preview] but it wont work and I dont event get any errors..kind of totally stuck any help highly appreciated. my config block below

```
.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider.
  state('home',{
    url: '/',
    views: {
      'funeralhomes': {
        templateUrl: './funeralhome.tpl.html',
        controller: 'FuneralCtrl',
        resolve: {
          funeralhomes : ['FuneralHomes',function(FuneralHomes){
            return FuneralHomes.list;
          }]
        }
      },
      'caskets':{
        templateUrl: './casket.tpl.html',
        controller: 'CasketCtrl',
        resolve:{
          caskets: ['Caskets',function(Caskets){
            return Caskets.list;
          }]
        }
      },
      'foods':{
        templateUrl: './food.tpl.html',
        controller: 'FoodCtrl',
        resolve: {
          foods: ['Foods',function(Food){
            return Food.list;
          }]
        }
      },
      'officiants':{
        templateUrl: './officiant.tpl.html',
        controller: 'OfficiantCtrl',
        resolve: {
          officiants: ['Officiants',function(Officiants){
            return Officiants.list;
          }]
        }
      },
      'flowers':{
        templateUrl: './flower.tpl.html',
        controller: 'FlowersCtrl',
        resolve: {
          flowers: ['Flowers',function(Flowers){
            return Flowers.list;
          }]
        }
      },
      'donations':{
        templateUrl: './donation.tpl.html',
        controller: 'DonationsCtrl',
        resolve: {
          donations: ["Donations",function(Donations){
            return Donations.list;
          }]
        }
      },
      'monuments':{
        templateUrl: './monument.tpl.html',
        controller: 'MonumentCtrl',
        resolve: {
          monuments: ['Monuments',function(Monuments){
            return Monuments.list;
          }]
        }
      }
    },
    abstract: true,
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
  })
  .state('home.login',{
    templateUrl: './login.tpl.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure of what you are trying to do. Do you want to include partials inside the home page or do you want to have a page for each (one page for foods, other for officiants, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

*Not fully sure what you try to achieve, but* I [updated your plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/r7ZZMDTrPepW8k5A57lK?p=preview) to make it running (just running)

I firstly used this statement:

```
// instead of this - state name
// $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
// we have to use url 
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

Reason? we have to pass the state url, not its name

Also, the home state is abstract, so we need to navigate to some state which is not. that would be the child, which must have the URL matching the otherwise. As doc says, we can do it like this:

```
.state('home.login',{
    // new line - the otherwise is in fact also matching this non abstract state
    url : '',
    templateUrl: './login.tpl.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  });
```

see:

#### [How to: Set up a default/index child state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-set-up-a-defaultindex-child-state)

> Give the 'parent.index' state an empty url. This will make it match the same url as it's parent state url, because it appends nothing to the parent url.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('parent', {url: '/home', abstract: true, template: '<ui-view/>'} )
    // ALSO url '/home', overriding its parent's activation
    .state('parent.index', {url: ''} )
```

Check the updated plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/r7ZZMDTrPepW8k5A57lK?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Your  snippet doesn't work as you have **abstract** set to true on your **home** state:

```
 },
    abstract: true,  // remove this
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
  })
  .state('home.login',{
    templateUrl: './login.tpl.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
```

Setting **abstract** to true, makes a state unactivatable. From the docs:

> An abstract state can have child states but can not get activated
>   itself. An 'abstract' state is simply a state that can't be
>   transitioned to. It is activated implicitly when one of its
>   descendants are activated.

ref: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views